# Displaying Django BooleanFields with dropdown selection

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am looking for a way to display BooleanFields a bit differently. 
My code is the following:

in models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
"""Variables to set the type of sauce desired"""
    spicy = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    regular = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delicate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    extra_delicate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How can I achieve a form where the BooleanFields display as a dropdown?
So, instead of having four checkboxes (one for spicy, one for regular.. etc) I would like to have one single dropdown with choice Spicy, Regular, etc so that the user can select their sauce of choice from there, instead of having to check the related checkbox.

**What I have tried:**
I tried creating a separate model for the sauces and then linked it to the Order model through a ForeignKey field. However, this doesn't seem quite right.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the user to choose a single choice, it might be better to use a single field instead of four booleans. If you are happy for the choices to be hardcoded, then you can use a `CharField` with choices instead of a foreign key to a separate model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    SAUCES = [
        ('spicy', 'Spicy'),
        ('regular', 'Regular'),
        ('delicate', 'Delicate'),
        ('extra_delicate', 'Extra Delicate'),
    ]
    sauce = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=SAUCES)
```

Comment: Thank you @Alasdair, will definitely be using CharField with choices. The main reason for using booleans was about another piece of code that triggers an action when one of the values was set to True, but I guess that I can also get the action triggered when a certain value gets selected by the user from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution will be to use [`Field.choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices):

```
class Order(models.Model):
    SPICY = 'S'
    REGULAR = 'R'
    DELICATE = 'D'
    EXTRA_DELICATE = 'D+'

    SAUCE_CHOICES = (
        (SPICY, 'Spicy'),
        (REGULAR, 'Regular'),
        (DELICATE, 'Delicate'),
        (EXTRA_DELICATE, 'Extra Delicate')
    )

    sauce = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=SAUCE_CHOICES, default=SPICY)
```

The model gets a bit larger, but, as the docs say:

> Though you can define a choices list outside of a model class and then refer to it, defining the choices and names for each choice inside the model class keeps all of that information with the class that uses it, and makes the choices easy to reference (e.g, `Order.SPICY` will work anywhere that the `Order` model has been imported).